# Stop Access Sub if one function stops (exits)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Macro which has three VBA Functions running sequentially (Through RunCode). I would like to know if there's a way on which if in first function a exit condition is met (either by error or by user input on a Message Box), the whole Macro is stopped and the remaining functions are therefore not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it - You could either modify your code in a way that the Macro calls one function. The function in-turn calls the other function and then that called function calls the final function. In a sequence of events.

`Macro -> FunctionA -> FucntionB -> FunctionC`

So when an error occurs, the function exits without calling the other function.

The other way you could do is, create a Public flag. So when an error occurs the flag is set, so every function will first check if the flag is set, if it is then Exit function else resume execution.

I would go for the first method. Function calling another function. Good Luck !

Comment: Happy to help ! I take you used the first method. Function calling another function?

Comment: Yes i did called a function within another! Worked like a charm :)